# What was The Shape of Water's Elisa really saying?

Tags: dialogue, the-shape-of-water

There is a scene at 1h 15m where Strickland is interrogating Elisa and Zelda.

It feels like, in the end, Elisa said something different from what Zelda repeated then to the angry Strickland.

Am I wrong or what did she really say?

Comment: Are people not supposed to be polite here? Why did you omit the Thank you part? And I think tagging the director of the movie in question helps attract attention of people who liked it and might know better.

Comment: Part of the Stack Exchange *culture* is that we do not want *[unnecessary](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)* comments (like "Thank You") as they **do not relate to /add to the question**. As for removing tags, unless the question relates **specifically** to that director is is, indeed, unnecessary and can be removed. Adding a drirector tag is only for BROAD questions relating the the direcotor's work *as a whole*.

Comment: Are you referring to "trivial" or to "f*** you"? 'cos, the first one she translated... the 2nd she didn't ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin the one which got him very angry and it seemed like she changed the final phrase. Zelda told him she meant Thank you or something like that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The movie is subtitled when Elisa has no translator and we need to know what she's saying...

At the point, we see her sign 'trivial' and Zelda translates for Strickland [and the audience]

[image]

After they are dismissed, she quickly signs something for which there is neither inworld nor subtitle translation - after he asks her to "Say that again" she signs it slowly and the subs give us one letter at a time..

F ... U ... *... *...  ..Y..O..U..

[image]

After Strickland asks a second time and Zelda translates as "Thank you" then we are back to accurate translation.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Elisa is phonetically spelling out 'Fuck You'.

[image]

Comment: Well, not phonetically, she's just spelling it out, letter by letter.